# In pandas, how do I flag a row in a dataframe if a date in one field matches any date within a list of dates?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a field with dates where the format is YYYYMMDD however some of the dates have a .0 following the date. See below sample data frame.  I would like to determine if the dates in the Entry_Date field exists in the list of dates in holidays. If it does, I would like to have a df['Holiday'] field to say "Holiday" and if it is not in the list, then "Regular" The goal is just to flag dates as holiday versus not. I am running Python 3.7.

I am trying to convert the Entry_Date field to integer and then date type in one line of code if possible (more elegant?).

```
# Data and holidays
dates = {'Entry_Date': ['20171101.0', '20161201.0','20170103.0','20190101.0','20191225','20190522','20190318']}
holidays = ('2018-12-31','2019-01-01','2019-01-21','2019-02-18','2019-05-27','2019-07-04','2019-09-02','2019-10-14','2019-11-11','2019-11-28','2019-12-25')
df = pd.DataFrame(dates)

# Code to convert to date format. This does not seem to work.
df['date_norm'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Entry_Date'])
df['date_norm2'] = df.date_norm.astype(int)
df['date_norm3'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_norm2']) 

# Match
df['Holiday'] = df['Entry_Date'].apply(lambda x: 'Holiday' if x == holidays else 'Regular')
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to mark `Holiday` vs `Regular`:

First,

```
df['Holiday'] = df['date_norm3'].apply(lambda x: 'Holiday' if x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') in holidays else 'Regular')
```

Second,

```
df['Holiday'] = 'Regular'
df.loc[df['date_norm3'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').isin(holidays), 'Holiday'] = 'Holiday'
```

---

To convert to datetime, you just need 1 step:

```
df['date_norm3'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Entry_Date'].str[:10], format='%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: The issue may be with holidays, which is a tuple of strings rather than datetime objects. I've updated the solution.

Comment: I tried both versions and all dates were flagged as Regular. 12-25-2019 is in both fields so that should have gotten flagged. Is it how the holidays list is formatted?

Comment: Thank you! that worked. Regarding "The issue may be with holidays, which is a list of strings rather than datetime objects" do you know a good link where I can read up on that so I can get a good understanding of the issue instead of just copying and pasting answers?  Thanks!

Comment: In general, if you are comparing apples to apples (i.e. same type of object) you will be fine. So it's essential to ensure comparison is made for same type of objects. For dates, the typically module to use is `datetime.datetime`. You can look up its methods `strftime` (datetime object -> str conversion) and `strptime` (str -> datetime object) for start.